# How to add the account number to an customer into quickbooks

Tags: php, quickbooks

I use quickbooks online V3. I tried to set the value for the account number to the customer using the script below.

```
$Customer->setAcctNum('586');
```

In `object/Customer.php` file, line `"AcctNum" =>` is present. However, I am unable to view  the above account number in customer thro API. It's also not displayed in the HTTP response.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to Intuit's documentation:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/customer

When you do that, you'll find that QuickBooks Online *does not have a field named AcctNum* which explains why you are unable to set that field.

The field you're trying to set *does not exist*.

Read the documentation and set the value in a field that actually exists.